# How to write a lua script to get multiple keys at once from Redis?

Tags: lua, redis, scripting

I am trying to write a Lua script that will return multiple keys back from a Redis DB. The script I am trying to run is:

```
script load "local values = redis.call('MGET', unpack(ARGV)); local results = {}; for i, key in ipairs(ARGV) do results[key] = values[i] end; return results"
```

I would then try and run it using evalsha (whatever the sha number is that it returns) 0 dog cat (where dog and cat are two keys I have saved in my DB).

Ideally, it would return "woof" "meow" as those are the values stored in the keys dog and cat. For some reason, this script will always return an empty list or set, and I do not understand why. Any help figuring it out would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`results` should be an array, i.e. indexed with number, **NOT** string. See [conversion between Lua and Redis data types](https://redis.io/commands/eval#conversion-between-lua-and-redis-data-types) for details.

In order to make it work, change `results[key] = values[i]` into `results[i] = values[i]`.

Also, in fact, you can just return `values`, there's no need to convert `values` to `results.`

Comment: Thank you! That fixed it perfectly. So my issue is that I was trying to index the array with a string instead of a number?

Comment: More importantly than the issue at hand, the OP uses `ARGV` instead of `KEYS` in his Lua snippet - that is incorrect and may yield troubles down the road

Comment: Yes, Redis can only convert Lua array to multi-bulk reply. Also as @ItamarHaber mentioned, you should use `KEYS` to pass in these two keys.